# Определение расширения файла в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в python сделать максимально правильно проверку на расширения файла ? Скажем, ко мне попадает имя файла и я хочу сделать проверку на то, является ли его расширения `.py` или нет.

Comment: Может проверить, что строка на `.py` оканчивается?

Comment: Но учтите, что расширение `.py` совсем не обязательно значит, что внутри Python-код

Comment: Если надо определить тип файла по содержимому, то используйте libmagic и какую-нибудь питоновскую обертку на выбор.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Используйте [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
>>> import os
>>> filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext('/path/to/somefile.ext')
>>> filename
'/path/to/somefile'
>>> file_extension
'.ext'
```

Answer (score 8):

> ко мне попадает имя файла и я хочу сделать проверку на то, является ли его расширения `.py`

`filename.endswith('.py')` метод возвращает оканчивается ли `filename` (строка, содержащая имя файла) на `'.py'`.

Если путь задан как [`pathlib.Path` объект, тогда `.suffix` возвращает расширение файла](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('my/library/setup.py').suffix == '.py'
True
```

Если нужно найти все расширения, то можно `.suffixes` атрибут использовать:

```
>>> Path('my/library.tar.gz').suffixes
['.tar', '.gz']
```

*"максимально правильно"* использовать самый простой читаемый код, который работает.

Существенным отличием является случай, когда имя директории задано со слешом на конце, тогда [поведение `pathlib.Path` отличается от `os.path.splitext()` или `str.endswith()`](https://bugs.python.org/issue21039):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext('pypy/rlib/rsre__gen.py/')[1] == '.py'
False # not True!!!
>>> 'pypy/rlib/rsre__gen.py/'.endswith('.py')
False # not True!!!
>>> Path('pypy/rlib/rsre__gen.py/').suffix == '.py'
True
```

Comment: `>>> Path('Я.и.моя.самая любимая.кошка.jpg.wtf.tar.gz').suffixes` => `['.и', '.моя', '.самая любимая', '.кошка', '.jpg', '.wtf', '.tar', '.gz']` — чёт мда)

Comment: Тут надо уточнить, что  pathlib в стандартной поставке python появилась только с версии 3.3. Может быть установлена отдельным пакетом

Comment: @FeroxTL вопрос имеет python-3.x таг. Текущая версия Python 3.5 (Python 3.3 вышел в 2012 году).

Comment: @andreymal вы какое-то другое поведение ожидали? Приведите ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеку `magic`:

```
import magic
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
mime.from_file("testdata/test.pf")
# 'application/pdf'
magic.from_file('iceland.jpg')
# 'JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01'
magic.from_file('iceland.jpg', mime=True)
# 'image/jpeg'
magic.from_file('greenland.png')
# 'PNG image data, 600 x 1000, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced'
magic.from_file('greenland.png', mime=True)
```

Код взят [отсюда](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-mimetypes-python/opredelit-tip-fajla-soderzhimomu/)

Comment: у вас ответ про mime-тип **содержимого** файла, а в вопросе речь всего лишь о **суффиксе в имени** файла.

Comment: Вопрос `является ли его расширения ...`, и я сам попал на него с гугла с запросом **определить расширение файла**, а эта либа помогает **определить тип файла**. Так что мне кажется ответ к спеху

Answer (score 0):

```
extension = '/path/to/somefile.ext'.split('.')[-1]
print(extension)
```

Answer (score 0):

Быстрее всего без всяких массивов и суффиксов:

```
ext = somefilename[somefilename.rfind(".") + 1:]
```

Comment: тогда уж `ext = somefilename.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]`

Comment: @dstwo в случае, если файл не имеет расширения, в `ext` будет вся исходная строка `somefilename`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#Слишком вручную, но это то что сразу приходит на ум
import os
t=input('Введите путь к папке: ')
docs,music,other=[],[],[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(t):
    for file in files:
        if file[-4::]=='.doc' or file[-5::]=='.docx':
            docs.append(os.path.join( file))
        elif  file[-4::]=='.mp3' or file[-4::]=='.wav':
            music.append(os.path.join( file))
#Сюда вставляем любые форматы
        else:
            other.append(os.path.join( file))
print('\nДОКУМЕНТЫ:\n')             
for el in docs:
    print(el)
print('\nМУЗЫКА:\n')             
for el in music:
    print(el)
print('\nДРУГОЕ:\n')             
for el in other:
    print(el)
```

Comment: Лучше так не делать. Одно неосторожное движение, т.е. один неправильно посчитанный индекс (например, если случайно написать `file[-4::]=='.docx'` вместо -5), и расширение не определится. Если уж знаете про `os.path`, то имеет смысл использовать `os.path.splitext` из принятого ответа.

Comment: Если как строку проверять, то лучше уж через endswith: `if file.endswith('.doc') or file.endswith('.docx'):`